# Prolog Conversion to uppercase letters

Tags: prolog, functor, uppercase, lowercase

Okay I wanted to ask if there is any way that i could change the lowercase letter to uppercase without adding the "". Sorry if this sound silly but I need this to run another program. I wrote somethin like this:

```
change(~A,X):-
   upcase_atom(A,D),
   X = false-D.
```

I need the output to look like:

```
X=false-P
```

But it looks like this:

```
X=false-"P"
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Why do you use `~` in `A`?

Comment: thats an operator defined earlier and i need to change ~p to false-P @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: The problem is that something that starts with an uppercase is not a functor/predicate/constant/... but a variable.

Comment: yeah i know but i was wondering if there is any way to change that @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I think not. This is rather fundamental to Prolog syntax. Furthermore `-` is not allowed in a functor name as well, I guess. You could use an underscore (`_`). You can transform it into `false_P`, but not `false-P`...

Comment: okay, thanks anyway @WillemVanOnsem!

Comment: I wrote an answer that - what I belief - comes closest to what you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note 1**: A **functor/predicate cannot contain a hyphen (`-`)**. You can "resolve" the issue by for instance using an underscore (`_`).
>
> **Node 2**: Building on that, if you write `false_X`, it will see `false_X` **as an entire atom**, so the `X` will not bound to the declared `X`.
>
> **Note 3**: You should declare `~` an **operator**, otherwise Prolog will error in this.

Based on these two remarks, you can however easily solve the issue by using [`atom_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_concat/3) instead:

```
:- op( 1200,  fx, [~]).

change(~A,X):-
    upcase_atom(A,D),
    atom_concat(false_,D,X).
```

The first line declares `~` an operator with one argument (and written like `f x`) with priority 1200. If one writes that, the query yields:

```
?- change(~(foo),X).
X = false_FOO.

?- change(~foo,X).
X = false_FOO.
```